# Is there a WordPress plugin similar to Word's "Track Changes"?

Tags: wordpress

Thanks in advance for your help! I'm looking for a WordPress plugin that will go beyond the existing features of a WordPress.org install and allow the same sort of red-lining, in-line commenting, "accept changes," and side-by-side comparison as Microsoft Word.

The use case is when one person (an editor) needs to provide feedback to another person (a writer) through comments and tracked changes. The writer can then move from edit to edit with ease and revise the page or blog post accordingly.

I know that I can get a side-by-side comparison of two versions of a post in the default features, but I'd like to do more. Anyone have a recommendation? Thanks!